# iOS view height and auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a viewController, which is configured for the iPhone5 screen size. In red rectangle is the view.[image]

To make this view show properly in iPhone4 - I used auto layout. But when I specify constrains such as: leading edge, trailing edge, bottom space and top space (in top space I even made constraint's priority to LOW ) - the view still goes partially down the screen as if my constraints don't work.
BUT if instead of top space constraint I specify view's heigh and delete top space constraint - everything works perfectly.

Does anyone can explain it please? Thank you.

Comment: autolayout uses constraint with higher priority if they have conflicts.

Comment: I know, that is why I specified top space as low priority - it still didn't work up until I deleted this constraint and specified the view's height constraint. Why did it help?

Comment: How should layout controls inside your's custom view? They also should have constraints, that specify yours custom view height.

Comment: Controls inside my view don't have constraints at all as I have only portrait orientation.

Comment: Maybe by deleting the top constraint you just allowed storyboards (or a xib) to translate autosizingmask into constraints for you?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because when you set up the top space constraint it will move the view by the constant you provided. iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 screen height is different but the constant remains the same so obviously it will behave differently. One way to troubleshoot your interfaces is to switching between iPhone4 and iPhone 5 on storyboard device on storyboard (first button from left to right on the bottom right corner of interface builder).

Auto-layout is all about experience in my opinion. I struggled alot with it until i learned. If you want your view to be attached to the bottom of the screen you should set the BOTTOM SPACE to 0 and specify the view's height like you did or adjust constraints for it's subviews so that the height is set dinamically according to the views inside.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that there is a lot of "Try and see what happens".